# How to extract values from column that have only one specific value in other column with SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table:

```
id       value     type
a1       146       out
a1       198       upload
bb       11        upload
q5       16        upload
q5       88        upload
ff       19        delete
```

I want to extract unique id's that have only type equal "upload". So desired must be:

```
bb
q5
```

How to do that?

Comment: `... where type = 'upload' and not exists( ... where ... and type <> 'upload');`

Comment: @wildplasser didn't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE type = 'upload'
   AND id NOT IN (SELECT ID
                    FROM TABLE
                   WHERE type <> 'upload')
```

Comment: you can't use T1.id in presto

Comment: Apologies. I was not aware of that. Please try the edited code.

Comment: it says PrestoUserError: PrestoUserError(type=USER_ERROR, name=COLUMN_NOT_FOUND, message="line 97:26: Column 't2.type' cannot be resolved", query_id=20210929_124417_01187_232w2). Where you got T2 from?

Comment: @french_fries, Can you plz try now.

Answer (score 0):

First and most common approach would be to use "not exists"

```
select distinct td.id
  from test_data td
 where td.type = 'upload'
   and not exists (select 1 
                     from test_data td2 
                    where td2.id = td.id 
                      and td2.type <> 'upload');
```

But I like to use left join for that case as it helps to avoid subqueries

```
select distinct td1.id 
  from test_data td1
  left join test_data td2
    on td1.id = td2.id
    and td2.type <> 'upload'
 where td1.type = 'upload'
   and td2.id is null
```

the third way would be more tricky but let it be here too

first, select those with that has only one type (having clause)
then, self-join on the id filtering only those who has type = 'upload'

```
select td.id
  from test_data td
  join test_data td2
    on td.id = td2.id
   and td2.type = 'upload'
 group by td.id
having count(distinct td.type) = 1
```

Just pick the one which performs faster

Comment: it says ```Column 'td2.type' cannot be resolved", query_id=20210929_122818_01015_232w2)``` im using presto, this  td.id doesn't work

Comment: @french_fries for which query?

Comment: for second onee

Comment: Sorry, I did not know presto doesn't support aliases. It is pretty common thing for everything that uses sql. Let me see

Comment: @french_fries can you try perhapsaliasing tables using "as", Eg. "test_data as td2". Like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51425392/how-to-left-join-in-presto-sql